# Slideshow images load on page reload Rails & OwlSlideshow

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, http

I'm facing the following problem: I'm using an external API that returns a image hash that has multiple images. When I enter the show page for the element that has such images, I loop through them and use OwlSlideshow to display them. The thing is that when I first enter the show page the images doesn't load, but when I reload the page, they do. Here's the code:

controller

```rb
def show
    request = HTTParty.get(BASE_URL + "properties/#{params[:id]}", :headers => HEADERS)
    @response = JSON.parse(request.body)
end
```

view

```html
  <div class="images">
    <%if @response["property_images"]%>
      <div class="owl-carousel">
        <% @response["property_images"].each do |image| %>
        <div class="item">
          <%=image_tag image["url"]%> 
        </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    <%else%>
      <p>No property images</p>
    <%end%>
  </div>
```

Comment: Might not be the most efficient way to send the images around. Have you checked whether `@response` contains the right information on the first call in the controller?

Comment: Yes it contains the right information on the first call